# 2 Thread access shared resource without synchronized keyword, still works fine

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Worker {
private int count = 0;                  //shared resource

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Worker w = new Worker();
    w.doWork();
}

public void doWork() {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {   //Thread incrementing count 10000 times
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                count++;          //Not Atomic operation

            }

        }
    });

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {    //Thread incrementing count 10000 times
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                count++;           //Not Atomic operation
            }

        }
    });
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    try {//halts main thread so that both thread race to increment count
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Count is: " + count); 
}
}
```

I copied this code from Cave Of Programming.
Every time I run this code, I get result as 20000 without using synchronized keyword, which is unexpected.
Is the code correct ?
My OS schedules both the thread correctly? (I know this is weird Question)

I am expecting unwanted result every time I run the code.

Comment: 'count++` is **not** atomic!!!!

Comment: Ok.@Paul  And what about my other questions.

Comment: Can you check how many cores your CPU is running?

Comment: count++ is apparently that small, that everything works fine (most of the time)

Comment: I had this same issue last time, but I found out that my computer is running on 1 core, and even though 2 threads are used here, they are running on the same core. No matter how many times you run it, it is essentially behaving like you only have 1 thread.

Comment: @McKevin Yes I am working on VMware . And it is running on 1 core.

Comment: Increase the number of cores if your host machine can support it (I think vmware has an option) , or use a different machine or you could just use your host machine to test it if your host machine has more than 1 core (which I assume should have since it's running a vm).

Comment: You are right @McKevin.I am on VMware which only has one core thats why those thread were treated as one.I came to know when i gave same code to my friend to execute who has 2 core and got result as expected so that comes to conclusion that Thread needs Multiple core to work as a Thread .

Answer (score 1):

First of all count++ is not atomic.
Secondly though you got the answer correct 2000, we cannot guarantee that it would be correct always.

Reason would be as follows.  Operation count++ is treated as a 3 step process

```
 1. Fetch the count value
 2. Increment the count value
 3. assign the incremented value back to count variable
```

So when thread1 is reading, Thread 2 might increment the value. Still thread 1 has ole value, and overrding the value incrmented by thread2

I would be definitely correct if you make the count++ atomic.  For this you can use as follows

```
 AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
```

and you could increment it using

```
 count.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: But it looks like he wants to make it fail intentionally

Comment: Offcourse yes, but he is in an assumption that count++ is atomic, which is not true.  Updated my answer WRT that concern

Comment: Yes @kaykay .I want to see failed results.

Comment: @HJK Don't think he's making that assumption. He is in fact expecting it to fail, which means he is possibly aware that the increment is not atomic

Comment: Run the sample as many times as possible, definitely you get different result

Comment: @HJK I ran it almost 50 times.

Comment: @JavedSolkar, I ran the same on my machine 64-bit, quad core processor and i got "Count is: 12833".  Answer is purely dependent.  But we cannot expect the right

Answer (score 1):

It will behave differently depending on OS and load on the system.

I executed the same code 3 times and got the different results each time

> $ java Worker
>   Count is: 10437
>   $ java Worker
>   Count is: 10395
>   $ java Worker
>   Count is: 10684

I used Ubuntu 14 (x64) with OpenJDK-7

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is that both of the threads increment the count variable from 0 by 10000 each, so the expected output is indeed 0 + 10000 + 10000 = 20000.

However, since count++ is not an atomic operation, this is not deterministic. Run it more times and you may get different results.

Comment: Yes @Mattias you are right.I ran it many times but got same result as 20000.

Answer (score 0):

The code is incorrect. The correct result is a coincidence.

First count++ is not atomic.

Second, a task might run till it ends and the other could run afterwards - no restrictions here. The schedule can decide to give so much time that a task actually finishes and than it switches or it is just giving enough time that count++ is actually behaving like atomic(just because of the time between switches). But the could could provide different results. In the end 2000 is a mere and happy coincidence.

Try to increase the loop size, in order to see different results.
In summary, the code is correct to provide incorrect results,as you expected, just expand you experiment.

Comment: Yes @Victor it Actually behaves like an Atomic operation.I think I need to run this code on different OS and see the result.

Comment: Just try different JDK, or just changing a version should be enough, I run your could and got Count is: 11990

Comment: Java is (mostly) not OS dependent. It's just that your sample size is too small. Try it many times, and you should see what you expect

Comment: I agree with kaykay, but scheduler might differ among vms

Comment: But as I advised and he also said, the sample is short.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code your for loops will executed 10000 times in both the cased so its obvious that it will give you 20000 as result.

**Advice:** Try printing intermediate value of `count`

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {   //Thread incrementing count 10000 times
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            count++;          //Not Atomic operation
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
});
```

Then you will realize the difference of with `synchronized` and without `synchronized`.

Comment: I know what synchronized keyword does.But as per my above code I can't prove it practically.

Comment: Tried intermediate values.o\p:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25

Answer (score 0):

@Javed.. I hope you have seen the join fundamental in threads..
Looks like Join is doing the job for you and also for me..
I have run your program 10 times and have always got 20000.
Also I tried a SOP such as Thread.currentThread().getName() before
the count++ in both the threads and then ran the program.
I found that there is no interlacing between the thread1
and thread2...All SOPs for Thread1 are displayed and then
the SOPs for Thread2 are displayed hence there is no race..
Thread1 finishes its work and then Thread2 does its job
hence 20000 will always be the result.

Comment: I already did what you did .But when I gave this code to a friend, result allways varies that is because of processor, we ran our code using single core .If you run this code on multiprocessor  I think you will also get different results.